# Restangular - Specific Function to Specific Factory

Tags: angularjs, rest, restangular

I'm working with restangular and so far, everything works very well, but, i have this issue that cannot resolve.

I define a abstract repository with the basic operations like this:

```
app.factory('AbstractRepository', [

function(){

    function AbstractRepository(restangular, route) {
        this.restangular = restangular;
        this.route = route;
    };

    AbstractRepository.prototype = {

    getList: function (params) {
        return this.restangular.all(this.route).getList(params).$object;
    },

    get: function (id) {
        return this.restangular.one(this.route, id).get();
    },

    getView: function (id) {
        return this.restangular.one(this.route, id).one(this.route + 'view').get();
    },

    update: function (updatedResource) {
        return updatedResource.put().$object;
    },

    create: function (newResource) {
        return this.restangular.all(this.route).post(newResource);
    },

    remove: function (object) {
        return this.restangular.one(this.route, object.id).remove();
    },

    };

    AbstractRepository.extend = function (repository) {
        repository.prototype = Object.create(AbstractRepository.prototype);
        repository.prototype.constructor = repository;
    }

    return AbstractRepository;
}

]);
```

And the specific respository:

```
app.factory('ServiceRepository', ['Restangular', 'AbstractRepository',
function (restangular, AbstractRepository) {

function ServiceRepository() {  
    //restangular.setBaseUrl("http://192.168.0.144:8080/api/rest/services/");
  AbstractRepository.call(this, restangular,'http://192.168.0.144:8080/api/rest/services/');
}

  AbstractRepository.extend(ServiceRepository);
  return new ServiceRepository();
}
```

And i call the methods :

```
ServiceRepository.getList();
```

And now i want to implement and function (getServicesByOperatorId) that only works in the specific repository, not in the abstract. So i can call it like this:

```
ServiceRepository.getServicesByOperatorId({"operatorId":7});
```

If i define the function in the prototype of the abstract it works, but i want i way to define in the specific.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You should extend the ServiceRepository, not the Abstract one. You must provide the extend at the child not at the parent

Comment: How can i do that? I try:   `ServiceRepository.prototype = Object.create(AbstractRepository.prototype, {
     getServicesByOperatorId : function (id) {
      return this.restangular.all(this.route + 'getServiceByOperatorId').getList(id).$object;
  }
    });

    ServiceRepository.prototype.constructor = ServiceRepository;`  And i can access to getList() function but not to getServicesByOperatorId({"operatorId":7});

Answer (score 0):

Finally i find a way to do what i want:

In the specific factory define the prototype and extend from the abstract prototype like this:

```
ServiceRepository.prototype = {
    getServicesByOperatorId: function (id) {
        return this.restangular.all(this.route + 'getServicesByOperatorId').getList(id).$object;
    }
}

angular.extend(ServiceRepository.prototype, AbstractRepository.prototype);
```

And in the abstract repository, remove this definition:

```
AbstractRepository.extend = function (repository) {
    repository.prototype = Object.create(AbstractRepository.prototype);
    repository.prototype.constructor = repository;
}
```

No i can access to de getList() method and the getServicesByOperatorId().